# account register not working in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a new project in visual studio 2012 express for web and selected mvc application; I tag index action in home controller with [authorize] and I taken to log in page and there I click register link and taken to register page and fill user name and password and confirm password and when I hit register button I get error
The requested URL.../Account/Register cannot be found or is not available. Please check the spelling or try again later.
the browser shows the stack  trace page only for a glimpse.
Please help

Comment: ok now I googled and found out I need to install/enable localdb feature; I did that and was able to start LocalDb instance from command line however it does not show up in local services list/also management studio does not list it. Now when I debug I get error  cannot  attach file ....mdf as database ...

Comment: ok!  I can connect to (LocalDb)\v11.0 from management studio; now register is working   however trying  to issue a select 123 from my controller  causes cannot attach file ..mdf as database aspnet error